# Material for a first course on cyclotomic fields

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation, cyclotomic-fields

I am aware that the two excellent graduate level books on theory of cyclotomic fields are:

1.Introduction to Cyclotomic Fields by Lawrence C. Washington

2.Cyclotomic Fields I and II by Serge Lang

Is there another supplementary resource (Video lectures, course notes or course web-page) to follow along with these books?

P.S. I have found the following: https://tlovering.wordpress.com/2015/02/08/cyclotomic-fields-and-fermats-last-theorem-tutorial-notes-and-problems/

Comment: What exactly are you looking for? "Material on cyclotomic fields" can mean anything from a basic exploration of their Galois groups up to Iwasawa theory. Can you clarify this part with an [edit]?

Comment: @mrtaurho I am looking for something to refer as an Introductory course on cyclotomic fields or maybe for the theory of cyclotomic fields needed to solve other problems in number theory (eg Catalan conjecture).

Comment: I personally like the notes by K. Conrad. You can find various topics of algebraic number theory and a paper explicitly on cyclotomic fields which i found quite good to read as an untergrad student. Here is s link https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/

Comment: Also a nice application is Dirichlets theorem, which states that for any $n\geq 2$ there are infinitely many prime $p$ s.t. $p\equiv 1 \mod n$

Comment: Gauss' law of reciprocity can also be shown using cyclotomic fields. A reference would be Neukirch Algebraic Number theory chapter 10.